# How to find the SVD when eigenvalue is $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

After calculating the eigenvalues, I get $1040400$ and $0$. Since one of them is $0$, how do I calculate (orthogonal) matrix $U$?

$$u_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} A v_i$$

I know there are a similar question here, but when calculation $u_1$ it's a null vector.  So, I don't see how I can find $u_2$.

Comment: Please show the computations so that we don't have to double check that your computations are right, and, if any, what theory you have looked at.

Comment: Details, please. You don't pay extra if your question does not fit in a tweet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVD: How to find the columnvector of U corresponding to a singular value equal to zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250359/svd-how-to-find-the-columnvector-of-u-corresponding-to-a-singular-value-equal-t)

Answer (score 0):

To find $u_2$, simply set $u_2$ to be any unit vector orthogonal to $u_1$. More generally, if a matrix with $m$ rows has $k$ non-zero singular values, then columns $u_{k+1},\dots,u_m$ are found by completing the orthonormal basis $u_1,\dots,u_k$ (by using the Gram Schmidt procedure, for instance).

Comment: "This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? [Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards."](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1).